# which one is more common?

Tags: sentence-structure

> The more I read the more I understand that I **do not know anything**

vs

> The more I read the more I understand that I **know nothing**

Comment: Is there a specific context to this question?  Also, it depends on what you mean by "common".  "I do not know anything" is more *standard speech*, but since "I know nothing" is more *poetic*, it might actually appear more often.

Answer (score 1):

"I do not know anything" is rather uncommon, but adding a contraction (i.e. I don't know anything" makes it very common. However, "I know nothing" is a lot more concise.

The two are largely interchangeable, but if you were really looking for a guideline, I'd say that "I don't know anything" is less formal, and often used in speech, but "I know nothing" is more formal, and often used in writing.

Of course, this is merely how I use it, and it changes based on who says it. If you say "I don't know anything" to the Queen, she isn't going to say anything, and if you say "I know nothing" to your friend, (s)he won't say anything either

**However**, avoid "I don't know nothing". It is sometimes used in the [Southern US accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English) and [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), but it is very informal. In most cases, it is [grammatically incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative#English), and will give people the impression that you are uneducated or similar